# How to create additional Sitemap files at DNN website?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, sitemap, dotnetnuke-9

I need to adjust sitemap of DNN website, but I need to do that using multiple sitemap files. I already managed to add custom url data to main sitemap.aspx, using `SitemapProvider`, but I didn't find so far any way to create custom sitemap files. Creating files in file system doesn't seem to be appropriate option because of 2 reasons:

1. routing won't get user there anyway
2. sitemap.aspx doesn't exist in file system, so looks like it's generated by DNN server in some other way, which (I guess) I should follow as well

Could you please give explanation and example of that or some links where I could figure out things? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually control when/how multiple sitemap files are created, you will not be able to do so using DNN Platform tooling/options.

If you need manual control over the sitemap and the files created you will be required to create your own, and you can place in a location to be served.  You cannot replace sitemap.aspx though without removing the handler registration (which is a potentially breaking change to DNN Platform and could be un-done on upgrades).

You noted the "auto" creation of multiple sitemaps.  Per the [SiteMapBuilder](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/develop/DNN%20Platform/Library/Services/Sitemap/SitemapBuilder.cs) within DNN Platform it will automatically split to multiple files, but ONLY when you reach 50,000 links, there is no additional configuration ability to split this up.

Comment: [DNN forum](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/sitemap-providers) desagrees with you... `multiple files will need to be created if you go above this limit. However, the core will handle this for you and create multiple files if necessary.`

Comment: Updated my response a bit

Comment: I see. Thanks, Mitchel.